# Как с помощью слотов-сигналов добавить значение в QTableWidget?

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcreator, table

Имеется пустой проект в котором есть две формы(Одна для ввода значения а другая чисто таблица) и два класса, каким образом можно через ввод в QLineEdit, добавить это в таблицу. Пробовал писать слоты для выполнения по типу:

```
void MainWindow::addinTable(QString data){
    QTableWidgetItem* item2 = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item2->setText(data);
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(1);
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(data));
}
```

Код прилагаю

form.cpp

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"
#include"ui_mainwindow.h"
#include"mainwindow.h"
#include<mainwindow.h>
#include<QDialog>
#include<QSettings>

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    MainWindow* m = new MainWindow;
    connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(send()));
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this , SLOT(send()));
    //connect(this, SIGNAL(sendData(QString)) ,m, SLOT(textchanged(QString)) );
    //connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)) , this , SLOT(send()));
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}
void Form::send(){

    emit sendData(ui->lineEdit->text());
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include"form.h"
#include"ui_form.h"
#include<qdebug.h>
#include<QLineEdit>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   // Form* form = new Form;
    connect(ui->pushButton , SIGNAL(clicked()) , this, SIGNAL(showadd()));
    ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);
    QStringList list;
    list << "One" << "Two";
    ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(list);
connect(ui->lineEdit , SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)) , this , SLOT(addinTable(QString)));
connect(ui->pushButton , SIGNAL(clicked(bool)) , this , SLOT(texter(bool)));
connect(this , SIGNAL(plus(int)) , ui->tableWidget , SLOT(insertRow(int)));
connect(ui->pushButton , SIGNAL(clicked(bool)) , ui->tableWidget , SLOT(update()));


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::textchang(QString data){    
     ui->lineEdit->setText(data);    
}
void MainWindow::addinTable(QString data){
    QTableWidgetItem* item2 = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item2->setText(data);
     ui->tableWidget->insertRow(1);
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem(data));
}
void MainWindow::texter(bool){
    emit plus(1);
}
```

form.h

```
#ifndef FORM_H
#define FORM_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Form;
}

class Form : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Form(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Form();
     Ui::Form *ui;
public slots:
    void send();
signals:
    void sendData(QString data);

};

#endif // FORM_H
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void textchang(QString data);
    void addinTable(QString data);
    void texter(bool);
 signals:
    void showadd();
    void plus(int);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif
```

// MAINWINDOW_H
main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "form.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    Form form;
    QObject::connect(&w , SIGNAL(showadd()) , &form , SLOT(show()));
    QObject::connect(&form , SIGNAL(sendData(QString)), &w , SLOT(textchang(QString)));
    QObject::connect(&form , SIGNAL(sendData(QString)) ,&w , SLOT(addinTable(QString)));
   // QObject::connect(&w , SIGNAL())
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: И в чем вопрос? Где проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что при вызове этого слота ничего не происходит

Comment: В метод addinTable программа заходит?

Comment: Пробовал ставить туда qDebug() с отображением значения, всё заходит, но не добавляет

Comment: Мне кажется, что Вы неправильно подходите к задаче. В данном примере использование QTableWidget неудобно (он по большому случаю удобен лишь тогда, когда у вас есть статические однородные данные, которые не меняются). В случае, когда данные меняются по ходу исполнения программы правильно переходить к QTableView + model + delegate. В этом случае Вы будете работать только с данными и не задумываться о том как добавлять-удалять строки и прочее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::addinTable(QString data) {
    QTableWidgetItem* item2 = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item2->setText(data);

    // Добавляем строку в начало таблицы
    ui->tableWidget->insertRow(0); // Здесь 0 это номер строки ПЕРЕД которой вставляется строка

    // Добавляем строку в конец таблицы
    // ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui.tableWidget.rowCount());

    ui->tableWidget->setItem(0 /*row*/, 0 /*column*/, item2);
    // или в конец
    // ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui.tableWidget->rowCount() -1, 0, item2);
}
```